# Using React Flow Dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I'm new to React and was wondering if anyone had experience in using the [React Flow](https://reactflow.dev/) library dynamically? As far as I can tell, the main way of using this library is to create a static `.tsx` file in the `src/components/` directory.

I would like to use a JSON entry from my MongoDB and dynamically create a flow chart based on certain flags/values within React. If this is possible with React Flow, I'd appreciate a link or help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's absolutely possible.

As you can see in this example, node and edges are expressed as JSON: https://reactflow.dev/examples/edges/

You can modify the `elements` array at any time and add furhter elements by just adding simple JSON nodes.

On top of that you can autolayout your diagram: https://reactflow.dev/examples/layouting/

Answer (score 0):

Check out the save and restore docs. You can save (or build your own) JSON representation of a workflow, then restore it as needed.
https://reactflow.dev/docs/examples/interaction/save-and-restore/